# If sleepiness come in our body , then we have to sleep or not?

Tags: mantras, japa, japamala, nama-japa

Its my personal experience   when im doing japa( hare krishna mantra) in day time i realized after 15-20 minute of doing japa  . I am very sleepy and lazy at that time and at moments i thinks that i will sleep now . so why sleepiness come in our body  after 20-30 minutes of doing japa.Mind also not works properly when sleepiness come in our body.

If sleepiness come in our body , then we have to sleep or not ?

what is the right approached to tackle the problem of sleepiness that come in our body ?

Comment: Chanting mantra's can be boring for some people due to the repetitive natue. In such a state getting sleep in normal.